# How to save method name and class name in database using javassist?

Tags: java, instrumentation, javassist, javaagents

**InterceptingClassTransformer class**

I want to save method name and class name in database at runtime.

1. I want to save method name and class name. I don't know how to insert data into database. I want to save only invoked method name and class name. Once I run the java agent it will store all the method names and class names in the database but my requirement is to store when method gets invoked.

   ```
                          try {
                                ClassPool classPool = scopedClassPoolFactory.create(loader, rootPool,
                                        ScopedClassPoolRepositoryImpl.getInstance());
                                CtClass ctClass = classPool.makeClass(new ByteArrayInputStream(classfileBuffer));
                                CtMethod[] methods = ctClass.getDeclaredMethods();
                                InsertMethods m = new InsertMethods();
                                int mid = className.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
                                String finalClsName = className.substring(mid);
                                for (CtMethod method : methods) {
                                    final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                                    String methodName = method.getName();
                                    buffer.append("System.err.println(\"Invoked Class Name: " + finalClsName + " Method Name: "
                                            + methodName + " executed\" );");
                                    method.insertBefore(buffer.toString());
                                    method.addLocalVariable("startTime", CtClass.longType); 
                                    method.insertBefore("startTime = System.nanoTime();");
                                    method.insertAfter("System.out.println(\"Execution Duration "
                                            + "(nano sec): \"+ (System.nanoTime() - startTime) );");
                                    method.insertAfter("System.out.println(\"Logging using After Method execution\");");                        
                                    PreparedStatement st = m.insertData();                                      
                              st.setString(1,finalClsName);
                              st.setString(2,methodName);
                              st.executeUpdate();
                }
                }
                                byteCode = ctClass.toBytecode();
                                ctClass.detach();
                            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                                log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error in transforming the class: " + className, ex);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    return byteCode;
   ```

   }

**Jdbc Insert Statement**

```
Here I am using JDBC to insert data into database.
`
        //Insert statement Class
        public class InsertMethods {
            
            public PreparedStatement insertData() throws SQLException {
                Connection con= DBconnection.createNewDBconnection();
                String q= "insert into method_info(m_key, m_value) values(?,?)";
                PreparedStatement st= con.prepareStatement(q);
                return st;
                
            }
        
        }
```

Comment: You are mixing up the injected code and the code that does the injection. You are only injecting some `println` calls and performing a database update within the tranformer. Generally, you should avoid injecting large complex code. Create ordinary utility code, like a method for storing your specific data (i.e. the two strings) into a database and inject only a call to this method.